# GetRelated() from System.Management equivalent in Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure namespace

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v, wql

In the System.Management namespace there is a GetRelated() method, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.getrelated?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0).

This gets the associators of a given [ManagementObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). Presumably, this functions similarly to the [Get-CimAssociatedInstances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-cimassociatedinstance?view=powershell-7.4) powershell cmdlet for interacting with WMI objects.

I am attempting to implement an equivalent in the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure namespace, which is what Microsoft recommends as the new API for interacting with WMI in managed code.

I have tried to implement a solution using a [WQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) with [ASSOCIATORS OF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement) clause. This required me to implement a path generator as the __Path and __Relpath properties are not populated in the new API (this might be a bug). However, in doing so, I realized that not all CimInstance objects actually have valid WMI paths, which renders this approach useless.

For example, the CimInstance of type 'Msvm_ComputerSystem' returned by [DefineSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/definesystem-msvm-virtualsystemmanagementservice) in the [Hyper-V WMI Provider (v2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/windows-virtualization-portal) has all KEY properties as null, which results in a non-existent ObjectPath, therefore querying with [ASSOCIATORS OF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement) is impossible.

I am looking for a way to query the associators without a valid WMI ObjectPath using the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure namespace or some other WQL query.